# Search for combinations of a phrase

Tags: grep

What is the way to use 'grep' to search for combinations of a pattern in a text file?

Say, for instance I am looking for "by the way" and possible other combinations like "way by the" and "the way by"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Awk is the tool for this, not grep. On one line:

```
awk '/by/ && /the/ && /way/' file
```

Across the whole file:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' '/by/ && /the/ && /way/' file
```

Note that this is searching for the 3 words, not searching for combinations of those 3 words with spaces between them. Is that what you want?

Provide more details including sample input and expected output if you want more help.

Comment: This is not what I want really. I want to search for the phrase and its combinations as I asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is probably by using regexps. But this is also slightly wrong:

```
egrep '([ ]*(by|the|way)\>){3}'
```

What this does is to match on the group of your three words, taking spaces in front of the words
with it (if any) and forcing it to be a complete word (hence the `\>` at the end) and matching the string if any of the words in the group occurs three times.

Example of running it:

```
$ echo -e "the the the\nby the\nby the way\nby the may\nthe way by\nby the thermo\nbypass the thermo" | egrep '([ ]*(by|the|way)\>){3}'
the the the
by the way
the way by
```

As already said, this procudes a 'false' positive for `the the the` but if you can live with that, I'd recommend doing it this way.

Comment: This is close to what I want, except it can find phrases like "by the thermometer" :)